# Rails : Check if model has an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I have a model called book. I want to be able to check if it has a book with the id of some number. It's a simple question, and I'm just learning. Don't be too harsh....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's simply:

```
Book.find_by_id(your_id)
```

It will render an object or nil.

Don't use `Book.find(your_id)`, because it raises an exception if no book has the expected id.

I strongly advise you to check http://railsforzombies.org to learn Rails.